# jQuery droppable center image inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to center an image (the draggable object) inside a div (the drop object) once it has been dropped but for some reason i cannot get it to work no matter what i do. I've tried using various snippets of code from previous SO posts, but none seem to work.

I have the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts at the top of the page and the Javascript below is also at the top of the page.

Edit: I'm using AngularJS for the drag and drop.

The current code i'm using is as below.

HTML

DRAGGABLE OBJECT

```
<div class="drop-box" jqyoui-droppable data-drop="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}">
</div>

<div class="drop-box" jqyoui-droppable data-drop="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}">
</div>
```

DROPPABLE OBJECT

```
<div class="merch-item">
    <div class="merch-item-outer">
        <div class="merch-item-inner" jqyoui-droppable data-drop="true" data-drag="false" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}">
         <img src="/assets/banner.jpg" data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
``$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".merch-item img").draggable({
            snap: ".dropbox",
            snapMode: "inner"
        }).mousedown(function () {
            var targets = $(".dropbox .test");
            targets.height(this.offsetHeight);
            targets.width(this.offsetWidth);
            targets.each(function () {
                $(this).position({ of: this.parentNode });
            });
        });
    });``
```

CSS

```
.merch-item-outer {
    padding: 10%;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.merch-item-inner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
.merch-item-inner img {
    width: 100%;
}
.merch-item-inner img:hover {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
.drop-box {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    min-height: 250px;
    min-width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're asking. I made it as one `.drop-box` with a black background in order to see, that on `.mouseleave` centers the image within it, fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/wfCw2/1/

Also, your javascript had referred to `.dropbox` when it should have been `.drop-box`

Comment: That's almost good. I have mutliple drop boxes that the draggable object can be moved to, so i need it to snap to the one that it's 'placed' inside - plus i need it to center not on mouseLeave, but once the user has let go of the draggable object. Edit: i placed the code you added outside of the mouseleave. It's almost there, i just now need to center the image inside of the div (no matter what height or width the div is that i'm place it in).